# ergo wergo weigo

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, linked-list

/* patch.hoc
   v. 1.2 10/19/2001 NTC
 */
load_file("nrngui.hoc")
create soma    // model topology
access soma    // default section = soma

soma {
   diam = 10   // soma dimensions in um
   L = 10/PI   //   surface area = 100 um^2
}

Comment: Regarding your last warning, are you trying to print the *pointer* value `n1.next` ? If not, try `n1.next->value`. Otherwise, change `%i` to `%p` if it is the pointer you're after.

Comment: Whoops that was a mistake. I edited.

Comment: Don't forget to set `n4.next = 0; /* or NULL */` so you can identify the end of the list.  Or you could set `n4.next = &n1;` to create a circular list.

Comment: embarrassing questions like this will follow me to the grave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a variable of type `struct ListNode` to a variable of type `struct ListNode *`. It looks like you want to assign the *address* of the struct to the pointer, not the struct it self.

Try this:

```
n1.next = &n2;
n2.next = &n3;
n3.next = &n4;
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
typedef struct ListNode {
    int value;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;
```

otherwise you have an anonymous struct as typedef happend after struct definition

explained here: [Pointer to self struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326954/pointer-to-self-struct-in-c)

Comment: Why just not simply:

`struct ListNode;
 struct ListNode {
    int value;
    struct ListNode *next;
 };`

?
Typedefs sucks because readability and debugging in bigger code.

Comment: I think in this case typedef improves readability, unless you want to always write `struct ListNode`. Not sure how severe the impact on code size would be.

Comment: I'd more likely to agree with ["Linux kernel coding style chapter 5"][1] arguments in this case.


[1]: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

And LinkedNode doesn't seam to be an opaque object, because author of original question is accessing parts of that structure not using any proper accessor functions.